# Why in Dockerfile echo ">>" does not append to file .env but rewrite it? How to create multiple line .env file using echo in dockerfile?

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, dockerfile, dotenv

I need to fill `.env` with production or test environment multiline data
I try to fill it in Dockerfile as follow below

```
CMD echo -e ${ENV_DATABASE_URL} > /var/www/.env
CMD echo -e ${ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID} >> /var/www/.env
```

command `cat .env` printout will be only one row last `${ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID}` data.
`${ENV_DATABASE_URL}` data will be lost

Why `>>` append to .env file not work in Dockerfile ?

Comment: Your solution should be added with the "Add an Answer" button, not included in the question itself.

Comment: As for the question's content itself -- which filesystem driver do you have Docker configured to use? (Default is AUFS, but that's not by any means the only available option).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -> Server Version: 24.0.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false

Answer (score 0):

`CMD` instruction creates a new layer in the Docker image and runs in a separate shell. Thus, when you use multiple `CMD` instructions like this, they don't operate on the same file.

There's a more suitable approach for what you're trying to achieve, by combining the `echo` commands into a single `RUN` instruction and using a shell command.

```
ENV ENV_DATABASE_URL='DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:db_password@bot_postrgres:5432/postgres_eis_bot'${LOGIN_USER_ID}'?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"'
ENV ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID="LOGIN_USER_ID=${LOGIN_USER_ID}"

RUN echo -e "${ENV_DATABASE_URL}\n${ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID}" > /var/www/.env
```

Or you can use the `printf` command, which allows you to easily format the string with line breaks:

```
RUN printf "%s\n%s\n" "${ENV_DATABASE_URL}" "${ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID}" > /var/www/.env
```

Comment: It's true that each CMD is a new layer, but false that you can't append to a file created in one layer in another layer. It's _inefficient_ (depending on exactly which storage backend is in use) because it duplicates the prior content rather than just being able to allocate only incremental space or operate in-place, but it works; see discussion of copyup and copydown in https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/aufs.5.html

Comment: BTW, think about `printf '%s\n' 'first line' 'second line'` -- the format string gets repeated as many time as need be to replace all arguments, so one `%s\n` is all you need.

Answer (score -1):

To add to @humza'S answer.

I use this format as it is way easier to read and extend:

```
RUN echo "memory_limit = 128M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
 && echo "max_execution_time = 60" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
 && echo "error_reporting=E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
 && echo "log_errors=On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini \
 && echo "error_log = /proc/self/fd/2" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
```

Comment: Every `>>` opens the file for append, and closes it when it's done. Why would you want to open the file five separate times instead of opening it _just once_ and writing all five lines?

Comment: f/e, `{ a; b; c; d; e; } >out` opens `out` just one time, truncating only at the very beginning, and leaves `out` open while all of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are executed.

Comment: because its easier do read... and i dont care how often its opened when the CI runner builds the container.

Comment: and what exactly did you save by this? 2ms? Thats BUILDING script.. not runtime script where not saving on calls could be expensive... each new employee can read my version without having to think about it, and can extend it in seconds. Thats way more important....

Comment: It's not easier to need to write `>` the first time and `>>` after it over and over, and make reviewers check that you used the right operators. Use grouping for your redirections and that source of possible bugs goes away -- you're writing less and there are fewer potential things that can be wrong with it.

Comment: There are also cases where the "separate redirections" approach doesn't work at all, like when you're redirecting from a FIFO or into a socket. Using the better practice is not just a tiny bit faster, it's also a lot more robust; it works in the corner cases, so it's less for you (and reviewers reading your code) to need to learn and think about to identify where those corner cases are and whether you're currently in one of them.

Comment: And I absolutely don't see how a new employee can't extend `printf '%s\n' 'line 1' 'line 2' 'line 3'` to add a line 4. Maybe you should be working on improving your hiring standards. (Remember, by the way, that you can add line continuations even within a block or simple command, so you can still have nice multi-line formatting).

Comment: KISS charles... what that means difference for each one of course.. you do you...

Answer (score -2):

The OP's question originally contained this self-answer:

> P.s. I solve this like, maybe are more elegant solution ?
>
> ```
> ARG LOGIN_USER_ID=2
> ENV ENV_LOGIN_USER_ID="LOGIN_USER_ID=${LOGIN_USER_ID}\n"
> ENV ENV_DATABASE_URL='DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:db_password@bot_postrgres:5432/postgres_eis_bot'${LOGIN_USER_ID}'?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"\n'
> CMD echo -e ${ENV_DATABASE_URL}${ENV_EIS_LOGIN_USER_ID} > /var/www/.env
> ```